# Larger Margins issues

Tags: margins

I'm writing the paper. The requirement of margins is Left- 1.5 inches, and 1 inch for the right, top, and bottom. The paper size is 8.5inches X 11 inches. I use the following code:

```
\usepackage[total={8.5in,11in},top=1in,left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

But, I found the margins are larger than what I set when I printed it out. 
Can anyone know how to solve it? Thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps provided us with a MWE that illustrates the problem.  Using your setup, everything is fine for me.

Comment: Welcome to Tex Stackexchange. Here is [more information about a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: The measured margins are left:1.875 inches, the others are 1.125 inches

Comment: Measured where?  Did you print in on a sheet of paper?  If yes, check the settings on your pdf viewer.  They often may add extra whitespace around the content of your page.

Comment: Print out my example provided below.  See what you get.  You should be able to tell whether the pdf viewer added extra whitespace.

Comment: Yes. I print it on a sheet of paper and measure it. By the way, how to check the settings and remove the extra whitespace? thanks

Comment: I just printed your example. the size is wrong. Do you know how to remove the extra whitespace in pdf setting

Comment: That's going to depend on your viewer and possibly your OS.  But usually this sort of thing is in settings (either for printing the document or the printer)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that I've encountered only on Windows machines.  I don't have access to one right now, but I will tonight.  So, I'll see whether I can get some screen shots to share with you.  But there is a setting when you go to print that allows you to select how the document will be printed.  Usually the wording is something like "scale to fit".

There should be an area from the print dialogue box that's titled **Page Sizing & Handling** with the following choices

- Fit
- Actual size
- Shrink oversized pages
- Custom Scale

[image]

I believe, but I don't remember, you'll want "Actual Size" and not "Fit".  But, my experience is that with different versions of Windows not all of these choices may be the same.  For example, it may offer *Fit the Printable Area* or *Shrink to Fit*

If you play around with the printer settings you'll eventually find it.  But still I'll see if I can get some screen shots for you.  On my Mac, I don't see the same choices and have never had this issue--at least not that I recall.

Consider the example below as a test page that you can print out to see what's happening.  Keep in mind the `showframe` key for the `geometry` package.  It can be useful for a number of things.  I've found it particularly useful for debugging this sorts of software/hardware issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,total={8.5in,11in},top=1in,left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

GALLIA est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt
Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae,
nostra Galli appellantur. Hi omnes lingua, institutis,
legibus inter se differunt.  Gallos ab Aquitanis Garumna
flumen, a Belgis Matrona et Sequana dividit.  Horum omnium
fortissimi sunt Belgae, propterea quod a cultu atque
humanitate provinciae longissime absunt, minimeque ad eos
mercatores saepe commeant atque ea quae ad effeminandos
animos pertinent important, proximique sunt Germanis, qui
trans Rhenum incolunt, quibuscum continenter bellum
gerunt. Qua de causa Helvetii quoque reliquos Gallos virtute
praecedunt, quod fere cotidianis proeliis cum Germanis
contendunt, cum aut suis finibus eos prohibent aut ipsi in
eorum finibus bellum gerunt.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=4pt,red,arrows=->] (current page.north west) 
                                        -- node[midway,anchor=west,blue] {top margin=1in} 
                                        ++(0pt,-1in) 
                                        -- node[midway,anchor=north,blue] {left margin=1.5in}
                                        ++(1.5in,0pt);
\draw[line width=4pt,red,arrows=->] (current page.south east) -- ++(0pt,1in)  -- ++(-1in,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: to add an image link to comments make an (unposted) answer and upload the image then copy the generated imgr URL into a comment using the markup of the form `[see this image](https://example.com/image-link)` then you can cancel the answer post.